# How to store and retrieve a value in different steps using github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a github pipeline, there is a job. I want to get a value in the later steps that was initially set in the first step.

```
jobs:
  backup:
    name: "Backup"
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Update Config 
      run: |
        export ORIGINAL_RDS_MAX_EXEC_TIME=123
    - name: Create DB Backup
      run: |
         // do some work
    - name: Cleanup
      if: always()
      run: |
        echo $ORIGINAL_RDS_MAX_EXEC_TIME // returns nothing
```

The echo in the final step of this job does not return anything, it seems like that original export variable is no longer present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) and reference that later on:

```yaml
    - name: Set output
      id: setter
      run: |
        echo "foo=bar" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

    - name: Use output
      run: |
        echo "${{ steps.setter.outputs.foo }}"
```

or you can [add it to the environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

```yaml
    - name: Set environment variable
      run: |
        echo "FOO=bar" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

    - name: Use environment variable
      run: |
        echo "$FOO"
```